# MongoDB shell history doesn't remember 'authentications'

Tags: mongodb, interactive-shell

The command line history of the interactive shell for MongoDB (2.0.4 on MacOSX Lion) doesn't work when I use commands on a collection called 'authentications', but it works fine for everything else, it seems.

```
$ mongo mydb
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: mydb
> db.aimsx.find().count()
45
>
```

Now if I hit up arrow, I get this:

```
> db.aimsx.find().count()
```

Works fine. However, now I run a command on the collection 'authentications':

```
> db.authentications.find().count()
795
>
```

When I hit up arrow now, I get this:

```
> db.aimsx.find().count()
```

No command on 'authentications' can be found in the history or in the `~/.dbshell` file. Anyone has an explanation for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a too-simple security mechanism.  We don't save things that look like ".auth" to the history.  There is a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5616) asking to make this better.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it, but it's nice with confirmation.